Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale returns incorrect result
I am checking the result of


console.log( Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions() )



In latest chrome Version 128.0.6613.120 it shows:
{
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "calendar": "gregory",
  "numberingSystem": "latn",
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "year": "numeric",
  "month": "2-digit",
  "day": "2-digit"
}

Which is an incorrect locale, my timeZone is Australia so locale should be en-AU
Microsoft Edge and Firefox correctly show en-AU
Is this a Chrome bug or am I missing something ?

I'm seeing the same. I've also tried setting windows locales and language settings to English (Australia) and am seeing the same behaviour from Chrome - although I'm not sure if this requires a system restart to be picked up. It does sound like a Chrome issue, though.

Also it seems that this is not the first time Chrome has had an issue like this, but it doesn't seem that that instance was resolved: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/bug-intl-datetimeformat-always-uses-en-us-culture/m-p/709751

It doesn't seem to be the latest version either, as Version 127.0.6533.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) does the same.

The interesting thing is that navigator.language; shows the correct locale.

submitted https://issues.chromium.org/issues/364338800
